# Starting the VLC Beta NEON with an intent?

Tags: android-intent, udp, package, vlc, neon

Just got a problem, I can´t start the VLC Beta (NEON) with an Intent. First, I tried to make an indirect intent by ACTION.VIEW but it doesn't work. After that, I decided to make an explicit intent with the following code:

```
try
{
    String Package="org.videolan.vlc.betav7neon";
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("udp://@111.111.11.11:1111");
    Intent i = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW");
    i.setPackage(Package);
    i.setDataAndType(uri, "video/*");
    startActivity(i);

    //Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("udp://@111.111.11.11:1111"));
    //startActivity(intent);
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

But the explicit intent doesn't work too. Any ideas how to solve this?